# "extern C" functions disapearing from C++ shared object symbol table

Tags: c++, linux, linker, g++, osx-lion

I have a shared object library that I am creating for a project and I am coming up with a weird problem where functions I have declared as "extern C" are not being found in the final library symbol table. I am linking the object file with the functions into the library but for some reason they are not in the symbol table. This is happening on Linux and OS X. I am using the g++ for my linking and compilation.

Edit:
I do not get any linker errors when linking. The library links fine. I can tell that the functions are not in the library because I have inspected the symbol table and they are not there. The command I am using for linking is as follows:

```
g++ -m64 -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.2/lib -shared -Wl,-soname,libQtCommercialChart.so.1 -o libQtCommercialChart.so.1.0.0 ../build/release/lib/chartdataset.o ../build/release/lib/chartpresenter.o ../build/release/lib/charttheme.o ../build/release/lib/domain.o ../build/release/lib/qchart.o ../build/release/lib/qchartview.o ../build/release/lib/qabstractseries.o ../build/release/lib/chartbackground.o ../build/release/lib/chartelement.o ../build/release/lib/scroller.o ../build/release/lib/chartlayout.o ../build/release/lib/versiontracker.o ../build/release/lib/axisanimation.o ../build/release/lib/xyanimation.o ../build/release/lib/pieanimation.o ../build/release/lib/piesliceanimation.o ../build/release/lib/splineanimation.o ../build/release/lib/baranimation.o ../build/release/lib/stackedbaranimation.o ../build/release/lib/percentbaranimation.o ../build/release/lib/abstractbaranimation.o ../build/release/lib/horizontalbaranimation.o ../build/release/lib/horizontalstackedbaranimation.o ../build/release/lib/horizontalpercentbaranimation.o ../build/release/lib/areachartitem.o ../build/release/lib/qareaseries.o ../build/release/lib/chartaxis.o ../build/release/lib/qabstractaxis.o ../build/release/lib/chartvalueaxisx.o ../build/release/lib/chartvalueaxisy.o ../build/release/lib/qvalueaxis.o ../build/release/lib/chartbarcategoryaxisx.o ../build/release/lib/chartbarcategoryaxisy.o ../build/release/lib/qbarcategoryaxis.o ../build/release/lib/chartcategoryaxisx.o ../build/release/lib/chartcategoryaxisy.o ../build/release/lib/qcategoryaxis.o ../build/release/lib/chartdatetimeaxisx.o ../build/release/lib/chartdatetimeaxisy.o ../build/release/lib/qdatetimeaxis.o ../build/release/lib/bar.o ../build/release/lib/abstractbarchartitem.o ../build/release/lib/qabstractbarseries.o ../build/release/lib/qbarset.o ../build/release/lib/qbarmodelmapper.o ../build/release/lib/qvbarmodelmapper.o ../build/release/lib/qhbarmodelmapper.o ../build/release/lib/qbarseries.o ../build/release/lib/barchartitem.o ../build/release/lib/qstackedbarseries.o ../build/release/lib/stackedbarchartitem.o ../build/release/lib/qpercentbarseries.o ../build/release/lib/percentbarchartitem.o ../build/release/lib/qhorizontalbarseries.o ../build/release/lib/horizontalbarchartitem.o ../build/release/lib/qhorizontalstackedbarseries.o ../build/release/lib/horizontalstackedbarchartitem.o ../build/release/lib/qhorizontalpercentbarseries.o ../build/release/lib/horizontalpercentbarchartitem.o ../build/release/lib/qlegend.o ../build/release/lib/legendmarker.o ../build/release/lib/legendlayout.o ../build/release/lib/linechartitem.o ../build/release/lib/qlineseries.o ../build/release/lib/qpieseries.o ../build/release/lib/piesliceitem.o ../build/release/lib/piechartitem.o ../build/release/lib/qpieslice.o ../build/release/lib/qpiemodelmapper.o ../build/release/lib/qvpiemodelmapper.o ../build/release/lib/qhpiemodelmapper.o ../build/release/lib/qscatterseries.o ../build/release/lib/scatterchartitem.o ../build/release/lib/qsplineseries.o ../build/release/lib/splinechartitem.o ../build/release/lib/xychart.o ../build/release/lib/qxyseries.o ../build/release/lib/qxymodelmapper.o ../build/release/lib/qvxymodelmapper.o ../build/release/lib/qhxymodelmapper.o   -L/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.2/lib -L/tmp/qcharts/lib/release -Wl,-rpath,/tmp/qcharts/lib/release /home/thinkbox/Desktop/libs/lib/lm_new_pic.o -L/home/thinkbox/Desktop/libs/lib -llmgr_pic -lcrvs_pic -lsb_pic -lact_pic -llmgr_dongle_stub_pic -ldl -lFNPload_pic -lQtGui -L/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.2/lib -L/usr/X11R6/lib64 -lQtCore -lpthread
```

The code that is not being exposed is in the file versiontracker.o. I can not show the code directly but it just just functions declared in a similar manor to this:

```
extern "C"
{
VersionUtils::VersionTracker* AllocateVersion()
{
    return new VersionUtils::VersionTracker();
}
}
```

Comment: And when you're trying to link against the library you created, do you get a linker error?

Comment: Could you include a minimal complete example along with the exact build commands?

Comment: Maybe you could supply a few more details--for example, which version of g++.

Comment: How are you determining that the symbols are not being exposed by the shared library.

Comment: How are you building the shared library (exact command line required).

Comment: Please show the code that you think is not being exposed and show how it is being placed in the library (relative to the last comment).

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that your linker optimization options `-Wl,-O1` are dropping unused code.  I.e. if your code library does not itself call the extern C functions, the linker might omit them as unused code when optimizing.
Try `-Wl,-O0` and see if the problem goes away.  If it does, the linker options are the culprit.

Comment: Actually, it worked the first time I re-linked it but I had some function names that I needed to change. I modified them and then re-built the project and they are no longer showing up in the symbol table.

Comment: You sure your rebuild was fully `-Wl,-O1?

Comment: Ya, I did a full rebuild of my solution. I made sure to remove the old libraries and re-built all the objects. I did not modify the Makefile after changing `-Wl, -O1` to `-Wl, -O0`.

Comment: Can you post your Makefile to the original question?  Perhaps that will shed further light.  And what if you try to compile some code that uses  some of the extern "C" functions in your library?  What happens when you try that?

Comment: I am unable to post the Makefile because it contains sensitive material. I will try to compile in code into the library.

Comment: I tried to add some code that calls the functions and they are still not being added to the library.

Comment: So when you run the code that calls the library, it blows up?